# Is there an image for the report server for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, docker, reporting-services

I am dockerizing our .Net solution with a SQL Server database. I managed to dockerize everything and I am stuck at the report server. Is there an image or a way dockerize the report server and configure it with my database?

Comment: SQL Server on Linux does not support SSRS. It can be used to host the database, however, the SSRS instance would need to be run on a different (Windows) host. If you are using a paid version of SQL Server, this would therefore mean 2 sets of licences. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported).

Comment: Check this out, maybe it will help you https://hub.docker.com/r/phola/ssrs

Comment: You'll need to build a custom Windows image.